# Код на ссылку с картинкой

Tags: html

Здравствуйте! 
В интернете я продаю различный товар с различных сайтов. 
Поэтому стал вопрос отслеживать наличие товара. 
Так вот, я пытался что-то смастерить, чтобы я мог видеть фото товара, который находится в он-лайне! И таким образом отследить наличие товара. 
Поэтому долго и безрезультатно искал какой-нибудь HTML код для воплощения задуманного. Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: порадовал =), HTML тебе тут не поможет, да и вообще тебе нече не поможет, кроме ксс подписки с сайтов или их рассылки 

Comment: Тут только RSS

Comment: Это для своего отслеживания, что посоветуете ?

Comment: Это типа рассылка? Вот многие предоставляют RSS нажимаю на неё и происходит что-то непонятное.

Comment: почему непонятное? берешь например в пользование гугл-ридер рсс, подписываешься на каналы сайтов и смотришь обновление ленты новостей от них, все элементарно просто

Answer (score 1):

Из личного опыта: написал скрипт на питоне(сайт тоже на питоне, но язык не важен) и кроном раз в сутки прогоняю все RSS-ленты клиентов с проверкой на наличие товаров, их модификации и добавления, на основании чего происходит обновление базы. И вам советую такой способ!
Имхо, лучше не придумать.
Ах да, немного справки: RSS - это всего-лишь канал в xml формате, данные и ничего другого(обычно).